# ReactJS issue when using capitalized methods

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, react-dom, codepen

Code pen link [here](https://codepen.io/dbejju/pen/dwyvjQ).

In my fist ReactJS tutorial video, I was writing hello world script and disappointingly its not working. I am not seeing any problem with the script or html tags I used but simple ReactDOM.Render() function isn't working. 
Code pen SS below. 
[image]

As you can see, the HTML block has root div
HTML block:

```
<div id="root">Why ReactDOM.Render() not working?</div>
```

JS(Babel) block has simple render function and in the right side pane the preview is showing default text in root element but not the  text.

JS block:

```
var el = <h1>YOU HELLO WORLD WHY DONT YOU WORK</h1>
ReactDOM.Render(
el,
  Document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is *case-sensitive*.

Try:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   el,
   document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

And remember to import React as well as ReactDOM.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REaEBo

Comment: `Document` also should be lower-case.

Comment: though the case senstive was visible error I was doing, earlier the code I copied from tutorials also didn't work because I missed the steps to add react and react-dom as instructed in project setup. Thanks